# check null and display accordingly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, null

I am working in ruby on rails and create index method to show all students.My students table include **EnrollmentDate** which **datetime** field and is **nullable**.

My table body part in the html to show the list of students is follows;

```
<tbody>
<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= student.LastName %></td>
    <td><%= student.FirstMidName %></td>
    <td><%=l student.EnrollmentDate, format: :long %></td>
    <td><%=l student.created_at, format: :long %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                  edit_student_path(student), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
      <%= link_to t('.details', :default => t("helpers.links.details")),
                  student_path(student), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
      <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                  student_path(student),
                  :method => :delete,
                  :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                  :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here the problem is null in the EnrollmentDate. I used localization to format the EnrollmentDate which creates errorwhen data is null. The error is

**ActionView::Template::Error (Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given.):**

So please guide me to verify the nil and based on that format happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
 <td><%=l student.EnrollmentDate, format: :long if student.EnrollmentDate.present? %></td>
```

You can also do it like this:

```
<td><%=l student.EnrollmentDate, format: :long unless student.EnrollmentDate.nil? %></td>
```

If this doesn't works then you can do it like this:

```
<% if student.EnrollmentDate.present? %>
   <%=l student.EnrollmentDate, format: :long %>
<% end %>
```

So if the enrollment date is nil then it will not display anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<td>
  <% if student.EnrollmentDate %>
    <%=l student.EnrollmentDate, format: :long %>
  <% else %>
    not enrolled yet
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Another - even better option - might be to use a presenter that always returns an usefull value (the formatted string or some string)

Btw: the naming convention in Ruby is the underscore multiple words not to use camelcase in variable names.